# Как реализовать приём файла моей программой на java из другой программы?

Tags: java

Имею программу А,  кторая генерирует  некий текстовый файл F и передаёт его программе В для отображения и внесения корректив вручную. 
Цель:  хочу написать программу С которая будет выступать неким связующим звеном между А и B и корректировать F до отображения в программе B.

У меня знаний маловато. 
Я понимаю, что не кто за меня не напишет то,  что мне нужно. Но я даже не знаю что искать. Гугл мало чем помог, скорее всего не о том или не так спрашиваю.

Comment: Что значит "корректировать F до отображения в программе B"?

Comment: Вы можете запускать java программу, указав аргументом путь к вашему файлу

Comment: Корректировать - значит изменить файл и потом передать его в изменённом виде в программу В.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил примерно вот так:

```js
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File(args[0]);
        
        if(args[0] != null) {
            try {
                String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())));
                System.out.println(input);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Программа принимает на вход путь к заданному файлу в параметр ***args[0]*** и обрабатывает этот параметр. Причём с помощью неё можно открыть файл из контектного меню любого файла "Открыть с помощью..." ну или как в моём случае принять путь к файлу из другой программы.
Есть одно "**Но!**": Если просто построить .jar файл, то не он принимает на вход а java-машина. Можно заморочится и поиграться с реестром и расширениями файлов (что не очень "портейбл").
Простых решений 2: запаковать .jar в .exe или создать батник который "скормит" нужный файл нужному .jar пакету

примерный набросок .bat файла:

```js
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin\
set MY_PROGRAM=D:\ReadFile.jar
set MY_FILE=D:\file.txt

"%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe" -jar "%MY_PROGRAM%" "%MY_FILE%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможен следующий вариант событий (самый простой):

1. Программа A создает файл и помещает в нужный каталог;
2. После программа A наполняет файл данными;
3. Программа B сканирует каталог, в котором должен находиться файл. Если файл существует, то берем его и обрабатываем дальше, если его нет можно уйти в ожидание и повторить попытку через некоторое время.

Примерно так:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        /** Дальнейшие манипуляции с файлом (запись и др.), в добавок
         * можно использовать блокировку на чтение, чтобы вторая
         * программа ожидала, пока ей не дадут доступ к файлу.
         * Для этого используйте java.nio.channels.FileLock */
        fileWriter.write("Text");
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}

public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        File file = new File("test.txt");

        while (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Файл не существует");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Также обязательно используйте обработку исключений, я их не обрабатывал, чтобы сократить код примера. Еще мне не до конца понятно, зачем вам связующее звено в виде программы C. Если вам нужно связующее звено, то обратите внимание на мою реализацию программы B, проблему можно решить по аналогии.

Comment: Можно попробовать `Files.newDirectoryStream()`, это должно вернуть все элементы в папке, что позволит забирать на обработку сразу пачку файлов за интервал.